# Use Parameter Name of #define in another #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to use the name of a `#define` parameter as another `#define` parameter? For example:

```
#define TEST 1

#define FOO(X) foo_##X

#define BAR(X) FOO(##X)

BAR(TEST)
```

Where it results in:

```
foo_TEST
```

Not:

```
foo_1
```

This doesn't work as it gives:

```
pasting "(" and "TEST" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Comment: #define BAR(X) FOO(X)

Comment: If you want to know the cause, the `##` processing operator is used to token paste (concatenate) two tokens, one from each side of the operator. When you do `FOO(##X)`, you're trying to concatenate `(` and `hello`, and the compiler error message tells you exactly that. As @lkanab suggested, you *only need* the concatenation to happen inside the FOO macro, as you did `foo_##X`.

Comment: decide your requirement first, also FWIW, a variable name != a `#define` MACRO.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm not using any variables here I know. I am actually using this to create functions

Comment: @jweyrich For me the inner macro becomes evaluated and then concatenation occurs resulting in foo_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 ways to avoid evaluation of a macro argument. Use the `#` (stringize) processing operator or the `##` (token pasting) operator on it.

Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST 1

#define FOO(X) foo ## X
#define BAR(X) FOO(_ ## X) // Prevent the evaluation of X with ##

void foo_1()
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

void foo_TEST()
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

int main()
{
    BAR(TEST)();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok looks like the closest I can get

Answer (score 2):

Remove the double '#' in the BAR marco.

See the working example:
http://ideone.com/hEhkKn

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO(X) foo_##X

#define BAR(X) FOO(X)


int main(void) {

    int BAR(hello);
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding to your updated question:

If you want to use a defined name like 'TEST', so change your code to 
`#define TEST TEST`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST TEST    
#define FOO(X) foo_##X    
#define BAR(X) FOO(X)

int BAR(TEST) (int v) {
    return v;
}

int main(void) {
    return foo_TEST(0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't include all the information. My bad. The keyword is `#define`d

Comment: Thank you for your help! But what if it is `#define TEST 1` and I want the function `foo_TEST` still?

Comment: you can use the first approach and use as parameter _TEST like this `BAR(_TEST)` other approach doenst exists because if marco TEST exists it will be used. You can check if it is defined with ifdef and undef the marco or simply use another name.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Sorry about that